# May Not Vs May Not Be Able To?

Tags: periphrastic-modals

For example:

> 1. His method may not solve the problem

vs

> 2. His method may not be able to solve the problem

Do both sentences have the same meaning?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

His method may not solve the problem.

He may not be able to solve the problem.

To avoid grammar problems, it is best to use /be able/ for people.

People are able to do this or that.

Comment: [Collins Cobuild English Usage](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/be+able+to) amusingly includes: ... 'be able to' [is] used to talk about a person's ability to do something....
_The animals are able to move around, and they can all lie down._ ' But I agree, 'be able to' is not always the best choice to use with a non-volitional-agent. / I don't understand the downvote, but it may be for choosing 'grammar problems' rather than 'usage problems'.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth   yes, living beings, ok. Tsk tsk to me.